# multiple facebook comment plugin in a single page

Tags: php, facebook

I have searched and gone through many so called solutions but none helped. 
I have a situation where i need multiple facebook comments on a same page for different `li` tags.

The code will make it clear I guess.

```
    <?php foreach($events_without_upcoming as $single_events):?>
    <li id="event_<?php echo $single_events->id; ?>" class="events" style="cursor:default"> 
       <span class="sn"><?php $i++; ?></span> 
       <span class="date"><?php echo $new_date?></span>
       <span class="venue"><?php echo $single_events->venue; ?></span>
       <span class="address"><?php echo $single_events->address; ?></span>
       <span class="option"><?php echo share_button('facebook', array('url'=>"http://www.xxxxxx.com", 'text'=>$text))?><?php echo share_button('twitter',   array('url'=>$url, 'text'=>$text, 'via'=>'Lightning At The Opera', 'type'=>'iframe'))?></span>
       <div id="fb_<?php echo $single_events->id; ?>" class="fb_plugin" style="display:none;"></div>
       <div class="fb-like" style="display:block" data-href="http://www.xxxxxx.com/<?php echo $single_events->id; ?>" data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="false"></div>
       <div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://www.xxxxxx.com/#event<?php echo $single_events->id;?>" data-width="470"></div>            
    </li>
    <?php endforeach;?>
```

The FB comment plugin is within a foreach loop.
Every `li` contains the comment plugin. 
I tried giving data-href a unique url as in code but its not working.
I have been trying this from morning but I couldn't find anything.

If i haven't made myself clear please ask anything thats required.

Thx in advance.

Comment: Can we have the real code, rather than a mangled version of it? I can vaguely tell that it is PHP.

Comment: sory for the vague code... i have edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<iframe 
style="border: none; overflow: hidden; height: 155px; width: 470px;"
scrolling="no"
src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/comments.php?api_key=your_api_key&elation%3Dparent.parent&numposts=1&width=470&href=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com"></iframe>
```

as we cannot find any solution with js so We are using iframe without any js libs,

it also helpful when we want to show comments dynamically.